# Why pass a pointer to a global structure?

Tags: c, pointers

This is going to probably be a stupid question but I am reviewing some code and I just don't see the point in what this guy is doing.  In one C file he has defined a global structure that has many elements of many types.  So from function "A" there is a call to function "B".  In the call they are passing a pointer to the global structure and then in function "B" some stuff is done and part of the global is updated.  Now This all seems like superfluous overkill since it is already a global. If the structure was local to function "A" I could totally see passing in the address to the structure into function "B".  However the memory is permanently allocated already at the very top of the C file.  In fact I can argue that there is a potential problem for someone else coming in a changing something and not realizing they have created a bug.

So I am sure there is a "good coding practice" BKM or something like that for doing this but I just can't see it.  So in short, why create an address pointer and pass that to a function unnecessarily when the variable is already a global?

Comment: It is possible the author of function B was refactoring the system to get rid of the global state, but never finished his work.

Comment: Yes it is very deep single step code.  Embedded system stuff.  A is the only caller of B and A is only called by one other function C.  It is a pile of layers to break up complicated things.  It is good code.  I just don't get this because it seems to only confuse the topic.  The global is used in multiple places but this part of the structure is only updated here.

Answer (score 11):

Passing the pointer is good style, primarily because globals are bad style. Perhaps the original developer is thinking about the possibility that the global may not be global, or the function that accepts it might possibly operate on a different variable (which may or may not also be global, but still needs to be identified).

Comment: It is used in many functions but all in this one C file.  It must be persistent in memory.  It is kind of an AI thing where it is constantly learning about this data and updating this structure which gets used to evaluate other things.  We have an RTOS in a different file(s) at a much higher level managing multiple access points into this C file.  I have 4 different things that can have data requested to this file from an external system.  All 4 of these very different things may request partial or full analysis by multiple functions in this C file.  is can happen “simultaneously”.

Comment: Sorry, but I think that was the answer.  I am finding that it is essentially used in 3 functions that all pass the address to other functions like I described.  The key is in a different C file where different subscribers to this data for different needs all have different calls to those three functions.  So we have multiple entry points into this file that all in some way modify or use the data in the single variable. To make it not a global means adding a glue layer with a static that we don’t have code space for.

Comment: Well I think we could still not pass it.  I think it makes the code more readable at the top layer to pass the address to the global instead of just accessing it where we need to.  But it makes it more confusing at the lower layers.  So I think it is not really gaining anything overall.  Thanks all for the comments!!!

Answer (score 1):

If the structures instance is global, and the two code files can access it, then obviously that is some unwanted coding. But there may be a case that the previous developer would have planned to create other instances and in such case his function re-usability had been challenged.

Its a good practice to use references to the structure during function intercommunication ,but if there is no some future plan of huge code change then using globals directly is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Function B was most likely being written with an eye towards reusability, and for whatever reason was never actually re-used.

*Ideally*, functions should communicate with each other exclusively through parameters and return values (and exceptions, where supported), rather than sharing global data.  This allows you to more easily re-use code in other programs where the global data variables are not present (or have different names).

If you're *really* squeezed for stack space, or have some other real technical limitation that makes using global data a significantly more attractive / less expensive option than passing arguments around, then globals are the right answer, but that should be *rare*.